# Android HorizontalScrollView Child Width

Tags: android, width, children, horizontalscrollview

I have an HorizontalScrollView that contain a LinearLayout that contain some custom views. For now, I fixe the size of the children by this line (in the constructor of the child) :

```
setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(200, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

What I would like to do, is to set the width of the component to 30% of the height of itself instead of the actual 200px. But I still need the height to "FILL_PARENT".

When I overrided the onMeasure methode, I tryed that :

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    System.out.println(widthMeasureSpec + "/" + heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

But I obtained the output :

```
1073742024/1073742586
```

So it look likes I can't do a lot of thing here, still I don't have a lot of information :)

Any idea how to do the trick ?

I precise that I'm testing on the simulator (don't know if that matter).

Comment: This should be enough : `@Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
   int height = getMeasuredHeight();
   super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height / 3,
     MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), heightMeasureSpec);
  }` .

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like get the dimensions of the screen

```
DisplayMetrics display = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( display );
int screenW = display.widthPixels;
int screenH = display.heightPixels;
```

and if the height of the component you want to take 0.3 out of, is the height of the entire screen, then do something like so:

```
setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int)(screenH*0.3), LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

I might have misunderstood your question, I just woke up :) Let me know if it worked or if you're looking for something else

Comment: The problem is that it's based on the size of screen and not of the parent View.

Comment: Oh, so the parent View is not the entire size of the screen ?